# Issues with Numba CUDA Kernel and Custom Class

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm encountering difficulties when trying to use Numba to accelerate a CUDA kernel that involves a custom class (Ray). The kernel is part of a ray tracing application, and despite using type hints, Numba is unable to recognize the Ray class. The code works fine without Numba, but I'd like to leverage GPU acceleration.

**Code:**

```
class Ray:
    def __init__(self,origin, dir, depth, n, reflections, transmissions, diffuse_reflections):
        self.origin  = origin   
        self.dir = dir
        self.depth = depth     
        self.n = n
        self.reflections = reflections
        self.transmissions = transmissions
        self.diffuse_reflections = diffuse_reflections
    def extract(self,hit_check):
        return Ray(self.origin.extract(hit_check), self.dir.extract(hit_check), self.depth,  self.n.extract(hit_check), self.reflections, self.transmissions,self.diffuse_reflections)
class Hit:
    def __init__(self, distance, orientation, material, collider,surface):
        self.distance = distance
        self.orientation = orientation
        self.material = material
        self.collider = collider
        self.surface = surface
        self.u = None
        self.v = None
        self.N = None
        self.point = None
    def get_uv(self):
        if self.u is None:
            self.u, self.v = self.collider.assigned_primitive.get_uv(self)
        return self.u, self.v
    def get_normal(self):
        if self.N is None:
            self.N = self.collider.get_N(self)
        return self.N

def get_raycolor(ray, scene):
    distances, hit_orientation = zip(*[s.intersect(ray.origin, ray.dir) for s in scene.collider_list])
    nearest = np.minimum.reduce(distances)
    color = vec3(0., 0., 0.)
    for (coll, dis , orient) in zip(scene.collider_list, distances, hit_orientation):
        hit_check = (nearest != FARAWAY) & (dis == nearest)
        if np.any(hit_check):
            color += coll.assigned_primitive.material.get_color(scene,  ray.extract(hit_check), Hit(extract(hit_check,dis) , extract(hit_check,orient), coll.assigned_primitive.material, coll, coll.assigned_primitive)).place(hit_check)
    return color


color_RGBlinear = vec3(0.,0.,0.)
if progress_bar:
    for i in range(samples_per_pixel):
        color_RGBlinear += get_raycolor(self.camera.get_ray(self.n), scene = self)
        print(i)
else:
    for i in range(samples_per_pixel):
        color_RGBlinear += get_raycolor(self.camera.get_ray(self.n), scene=self)
```

**Specific Issues:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\jj.py", line 668, in <module>
    frame = Sc.render(samples_per_pixel=1)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\jj.py", line 354, in render
    cuda_get_raycolor[128, 128](self.camera.get_ray(self.n), self, result)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\dispatcher.py", line 539, in __call__
    return self.dispatcher.call(args, self.griddim, self.blockdim,
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\dispatcher.py", line 673, in call
    kernel = _dispatcher.Dispatcher._cuda_call(self, *args)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\dispatcher.py", line 680, in _compile_for_args
    argtypes = [self.typeof_pyval(a) for a in args]
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\dispatcher.py", line 680, in <listcomp>
    argtypes = [self.typeof_pyval(a) for a in args]
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numba\cuda\dispatcher.py", line 687, in typeof_pyval
    return typeof(val, Purpose.argument)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typing\typeof.py", line 37, in typeof
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Cannot determine Numba type of <class '__main__.Ray'>
```

Comment: Have you tried using [jitclass](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jitclass.html)?

Comment: `  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type pyobject
During: typing of argument at <string> (2)
File "<string>", line 2:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: Cannot determine Numba type of <class '__main__.vec3'>
- argument 1: Cannot determine Numba type of <class '__main__.vec3'>`